# How to use multiple viewports in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, viewport

I need to show the same object in OpenGL in two different viewports, for instance, one using ortographic projection and the other using perspective. In order to do this, do I need to draw again the object after each call to glViewport()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nehe has [a good tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/multiple_viewports/20002/) on how to do this, and his site is generally a good resource for OpenGL questions.

Comment: For me, the linked article suggests a "yes, [you have to]" answer - but its author seems to *want* to draw something different on each viewport. Therefore, I'd still appreciate if someone confirmed in plain words if it's "yes, you have to redraw objects in each viewport", or "no, you don't have to - see <some-link>"

Comment: As I understand the the OpenGL pipeline, in order to redraw something from a different transformation, the vertices must be passed back into the pipeline with the new transformation, so yeah you will have to redraw for sure.

Answer (score 10):

```
 // normal mode
  if(!divided_view_port)
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
else
{
    // right bottom
    glViewport(w/2, h/2, w, h);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluLookAt(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    display();

    // left bottom
    glViewport(0, h/2, w/2, h);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    display();

    // top right
    glViewport(w/2, 0, w, h/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    display();

    // top left
    glViewport(0, 0, w/2, h/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    display();
}
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

if (w <= h)
    glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, 
            -2.0 * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w, 2.0 * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w, 
    -10.0, 100.0); 
else
    glOrtho(-2.0 * (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 2.0 * (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 
    -2.0, 2.0, 
    -10.0, 100.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Minimal runnable example**

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327092/895245), but more direct and compilable. Output:

[image]

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

static int width;
static int height;

static void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutWireTeapot(1);

    glViewport(width/2, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutWireTeapot(1);

    glViewport(0, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutWireTeapot(1);

    glViewport(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutWireTeapot(1);

    glFlush();
}

static void reshape(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -o main.out main.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut
./main.out
```

I think that in modern OpenGL 4 you should just render to textures, and then place those textures orthogonaly on the screen, see this as a starting point: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

Tested on OpenGL 4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.63, Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Not worth an explanation?

Comment: @TinyGiant Thanks for feedback. What part is not clear? From the code it is easy to see that `glViewport` is called multiple times.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: Yes, but without some explanation of *what* it means to use `glViewport`, the reader has no idea why that call matters or what it does. Granted, none of the answers on this question are good, but if you're going to answer an older question, you ought to be willing to be significantly better than the rest. And that means being comprehensive, not merely being compilable.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you mean to go into `glViewport` internals / details of how it interacts with other calls? Or just explain it's arguments? Internals I don't know, arguments I suppose someone who came here would know already, but I could explain.

Comment: I have to agree with Nicol here: the code may compile, but the reader needs some explanation that directly answers the question. Either, "yes, you can render two different camera views in a single draw call" or "no, you must make to draw calls to render two different camera views".

Answer (score 3):

yes,

and you should also change the scissor settings to have a clean separation between the two views if they are in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

In GL 4 you can render to many viewports in one rendering pass. See [ARB_viewport_array](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_viewport_array.txt) and related concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Think of OpenGL as being nothing more than commands which prepare you to output to the window you're currently working with.

There's two commands with OpenGL that even NEHE's tutorials don't tell you the importance of:

wglCreateContext - which takes a window device context DC, can be obtained from ANY window - whether it's a user control, a windows form, a GL window, or another application window (like notepad). This creates an OpenGL device context - they refer to as a resource context - which you later use with ...

wglMakeCurrent - which takes two parameters, the Device Context you're dealing with (the parameter passed in for the Windows Device Context in wglCreateContext) - and the Resource Context that returns.

Leveraging ONLY these two things - here's my advice:

NEHE's tutorial provides a solution that leverages the existing window ONLY and segments the screen for drawing. Here's the tutorial: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/multiple_viewports/20002/

Leveraging glViewport you'll need to re-draw on every update.

That's one method.

But there's another - less graphically and processor intense method:

Create a window for each view by leveraging a user control.

Each window has it's own hWnd.

Get the DC, process the wglcreatecontext, and then, on a timer (mine is 30 frames a second), if you detect state change, then select wglMakeCurrent for that view and redraw. Otherwise, just skip the section entirely.

This conserves valuable processing power, and also reduces the code from having to manage the window and viewport calculations manually.