# OpenGL subwindows

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

I am writing a small program in OpenGL on my Mac. I have a question considering subwindows. I have created two subwindows in my main window. Everything works fine to that point. I can draw in both of them. But i want something different. I want to draw (with my mouse) in one  window and simultanously get a drawing in the other window.

Now its not even possible to get the same drawing in both windows. If i want to see something i always have to draw in that one particular window.

Do you have some ideas maybe how to do this. Or do you have an example perhaps. Unfortunately i couldnt find much information on the topic "subwindows".

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726379/multiple-viewports-in-opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is not a scene graph. All what it gives you are the computer equivalents of pencils and crayons. So you draw something to a framebuffer, it will show up in only that one framebuffer.

You want to draw a scene from multiple vantage points? Then you have to draw that scene multiple times from those choosen vantage points to the designated viewports.

Comment: Hm, thanks for your reply. So i have to create multiple viewports. But how is it possible to see the viewport in different subwindows.This is something i dont understand. Any examples?

Comment: @buddy: If you're working with multiple windows, then each window has its own OpenGL context; at any time a thread has exactly one or none OpenGL active. On MacOS X NSOpenGLView takes care of propperly activating the OpenGL context before entering any drawing handler. Another method is using a single OpenGL window and using a combination of glViewport and glScissor to render into subregions of that window (this is for example how Blender does it - it renders literally everything, i.e. 3D model, UI, script text and so on using OpenGL).