# Multiple viewports for GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl

I saw this article [How to use multiple viewports in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726379/how-to-use-multiple-viewports-in-opengl), and there are some answers says just resize viewport and generate new scene to make multiple viewports, but could I make multiple contexts point to same window, and set viewport at different location to make them exist at same time, if it's true, how do I do it in C++ GLFW?

***Sorry, I am new to OpenGL***

Comment: Do you mean multiple opengl contexts pointing to the same window? That doesn't sound like a good idea. Why not render all viewpoints to textures and render the resulting textures as squares in your final window?

Comment: Is it possible to create contexts point to same windows?

Comment: @Botje I want a simple solution, and easy to understand, I think it's too complex

Comment: Can you explain why you think multiple contexts would simplify your problem?

Comment: It's just for habit, I always process separate things with separate context

Comment: I don't think you can share the window between different contexts. But you can use the different contexts to render to textures, as I said.

Comment: Could you show me the part of program as you said with GLFW? And post it to the answer

Comment: Do you mean multiple contexts or split-screen?

Comment: I want multiple contexts for same window

Comment: Render all contexts to texture are complex, we need allocate additional memory for buffer

Comment: @MichaeltLoL glfwCreateWindow can share a context to multiple window, so it's a window point to a context, and context not include a window pointer, how do OpenGL know which window should it output to?